discover and mount all the SMB shared folders of a server
I have a Synology NAS serving shared folders with SMB.
On Windows and MAC I just have to indicate the IP of the NAS and all the shared folder are discovered and mounted.
On linux (the latest Debian) (with cifs) I can only mount each folder individually. Meaning I have to know exactly the name of the folder to mount.
I would like to have all the shared folders discovered automatically under a unique mounting point like on the others OSs

After the WannaCry malware epidemic, Microsoft and computer security professionals in general rapidly deprecated SMBv1 and NetBIOS. As those protocol versions are now disabled by default (for good reason!), the SMB protocol unfortunately lost the NetBIOS-based discovery protocol that was used to announce SMB shares on non-ActiveDirectory networks.
Microsoft is using WS-Discovery as a replacement protocol for discovering SMB shares on a network segment that is not being centrally managed using Active Directory, but unfortunately Linux has very little WS-Discovery client-side support at the moment.
(On networks with Active Directory and its associated dynamic DNS service, Windows systems will use DNS SRV records to announce and find SMB shares.)
Apparently KDE has some support for discovering SMB shares announced using WS-Discovery, but Gnome doesn't. It seems you would need some kind of a scriptable tool for discovering and listing SMB shares, which could then be used to produce a series of commands to mount the shares. As far as I know, such a tool does not exist as yet.
Here is a quite rudimentary script-based tool for discovering WS-Discovery-capable hosts and printers:
https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2020/07/08/a-linux-command-line-utility-to-discover-and-list-wsd-enabled-computers-and-printers-on-a-home-network/
It might be possible to adapt it for the purpose of finding and listing any announced SMB shares.
